# Unfold the loop three times

Tags: java, loops, unfold

I got this Java function and I have to write the piece of code which results by unfolding the loop three times. What does it mean?

```
int f(int x, int y) {
   while (true) {
       int m = x % y;
       if(m == 0) return y;
       x = y;
       y = m;
   }
}
```

Comment: Presumably, "unfolding" is the same as "unrolling", so see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling) for what it means.

Comment: @Andreas i read about it but still don't get how to apply at my function

Answer (score 0):

It means to repeat the code inside the loop a number of times, then refactoring the code to optimize it.

Let's see how it goes if we repeat once.

```java
int f(int x, int y) {
    while (true) {
        int m = x % y;
        if(m == 0) return y;
        x = y;
        y = m;
        
        m = x % y;
        if(m == 0) return y;
        x = y;
        y = m;
    }
}
```

By rotating the use of the variables, we can eliminate the two *simple* assignments in the middle, thereby optimizing the code.

```java
int f(int x, int y) {
    while (true) {
        int m = x % y;
        if(m == 0) return y;
        
        x = y % m;
        if(x == 0) return m;
        y = x;
        x = m;
    }
}
```

Now repeat it one more time, and rotate the variables in the third copy, for a total of 3 times the "same" code, as specified in the assignment.

I'll leave it to you to do that, since it is your assignment to complete. If done correctly, you'll find that there are no *simple* assignments in the result.